# Should we love Satan since he is our greatest enemy?

Tags: exegesis, satan, gospel-of-matthew, love

Jesus asked us to love our enemy [Mat 5:43-44](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+5%3A43-44&version=NIV):

> <sup>43</sup>“You have heard that it was said, ‘Love your neighbor and hate your enemy.’ <sup>44</sup>But I tell you, love your enemies and pray for those who persecute you,

So, should we love Satan?

Comment: The Bible does not really separate evil from Satan but they have a inexpressible unity of nature.  The bible does not indicate anything redeemable, or admirable, or even pitiful in those absolutely separated from God.  Therefore to imagine some kind of love to a being we are to 100% oppose, who opinions and action we are to hate and which we should have no other kind of relationship leaves little room for even abstract philosophy about love. Even God who is love nowhere indicates in the Bible that he loves devils in their damned state.

Comment: Catholicism would probably say *yes*, since God loves the Devil: http://youtu.be/AAnDmYnjH-w

Comment: This is nowhere near an answer, but I can't resist recounting a very old memory. When I was in elementary school, one of the nuns told us that we should love everyone, even the devil. When I mentioned this to my father, he said "In my house, anyone who loves the devil gets a spanking."

Answer (score 28):

Our command to love our enemies is intended for our human enemies, whom God also loves.  God's love for us is shown through His sacrifice on the cross, and also in the statement that it is His desire that every man come to repentance.

Satan, on the other hand, cannot come to repentance, and there is no hope for his redemption.

A good answer with scripture references can be found here: [Should We Love Satan?](http://www.westarkchurchofchrist.org/library/lovesatan.htm)

The following is copied directly from the article:

> A young girl asked me this question: "Should we love Satan?" She
>   clarified her question by saying Jesus taught us to love our enemies
>   (Matthew 5:44-45) and that Satan is our enemy (1 Peter 5:8).
>
> After careful consideration of the question, I answered something like
>   this. All of mankind has hope; the apostle Paul said he had a goal or
>   an aim to "... present every man perfect in Christ Jesus" (Colossians
>   1:28). We are to seek every man's highest good -- that is to love him
>   that he might be saved. On the other hand, Satan's eternity has been
>   sealed, there is not anything that man can do or should do to change
>   that. We are told that Satan has gone forth with great wrath because
>   he knows that he has but a short time (Revelation 12:12). Jesus tells
>   us that he has prepared a lake of fire for the devil and his angels
>   (Matthew 25:41).
>
> What should be our attitude towards Satan? We should follow the
>   example of Michael the archangel who refused to get involved with
>   Satan, even in a discussion. Michael was willing to leave Satan in
>   God's hands. He said, "The Lord rebuke thee" (Jude 9). Our attitude
>   towards Satan should be to resist him. God said, "Resist the devil,
>   and he will flee from you" (James 4:7). We are to be on guard and
>   watchful because Satan is our enemy trying to devour us (1 Peter 5:8).
>
> Satan has many devices; he is tricky. He is trying to lead us to the
>   grave separated from God (2 Corinthians 2:11). He is trying to blind
>   our minds to the word of God through unbelief (2 Corinthians 4:4).
>
> We are not instructed in the inspired scripture to love Satan, but to
>   overcome him. The only way we can do this is to fill our hearts with
>   the word of God (1 John 2:14). Jesus is our example; Satan threw
>   everything he had at Jesus -- the lust of the flesh, the lust of the
>   eyes, and the pride of life -- and each time Jesus would answer, "It
>   is written." He defeated Satan with the word of God, and He did not
>   try to convert him (Matthew 4:1-11) because Satan's eternity in the
>   lake of fire had already been sealed.
>
> In the context of Matthew 5, when Jesus said, "Love your enemies," He
>   was discussing our relationship with our fellow man and not with
>   Satan.
>
> Roy Dunavin West-Ark Church of Christ, Fort Smith, AR

**In addition to the above, your question ignores the context.**

The verse is in the midst of a series of "You have heard it said" statements that show that the Old Testament law is the bare minimum of what is required for righteousness, and in this example, the statement that we should love our enemy was "You have heard that it was said, 'Love your neighbor'"  The essence of the verse is (like the surrounding verses) that the law says to *do this*, but the true requirement for perfect love and righteousness is to *do this more perfect fulfillment of the law of love*...

In the context of this verse, "thy neighbor" was clearly meant to denote human relationships.  There is no reason, *other than to set up a [straw-man argument](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/straw-man.html)*, to believe that "your enemy" is meant to be viewed in a different context.

Comment: Great... now rise another question, just why oh why God didn't give a chance to Satan to repent.

Comment: Not being omnipotent myself, the best answer for that is "that He CHOSE not to."  I don't have a solid answer for this myself, and I don't feel like I need to understand the mind of God completely to trust him.  However, others have taken a crack at this question, too.  http://www.gotquestions.org/angels-repent.html

Comment: @Phelios - I see no statement in the Bible as to whether or not God gave Satan a chance to repent. We are not given information one way or another. I think we should give God the benefit of the doubt rather than Satan and assume He acted 100% justly.

Comment: I am not a Christian, but I see your scriptural support and can admire the case you make.  That said, just in terms of my feelings, I would find it oddly "emotionally admirable" if a Christian were to say, "Yes, I do love Satan, or at least hope to, because I have come to a level of compassion in which I extend love to all sentient beings, of which Satan is one.  He is an evil being, don't condone evil actions or support his causes, but I have nothing in my heart but love for him, *whether it makes any difference to his fate or not*!"  I find this a poetic consideration, for what it's worth.

Comment: @Sufendy, who says that Satan didn't have a chance to repent? Perhaps God's final statement on the matter is foreknowledge of what Satan's choice(s) would be without engineering them. Perhaps choosing to reject God when you have beheld him in his fullness is something that nobody ever _would_ change his mind about.

Answer (score 3):

If we consider that love is an action, I don't think it's possible to love Satan in the same way that we love our neighbor, and we cannot do so without hating God.

If we look at the parable of the [Good Samaritan](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2010:25-37&version=NIV), we love our neighbor (our fellow human) by taking care of them when they are in need.  Jesus several times shows love to other people by serving them and God calls us to do the same.  In this sense, there is really no way we can "love" Satan because we cannot do anything for him as we can a human.

Also, we love others by praying for their salvation and telling others about Christ.  But it is quite clear in the Bible that [Satan's fate](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=revelation%2020:10-20:10&version=KJV) is already sealed, so there is nothing we can do for him in that regard.

Lastly, another way to "love" Satan is to basically serve his desires, but we cannot do that without disobeying God.

So, I don't think it is really possible to love Satan, because we cannot do so in the sense that we love other humans, and we cannot do so without going against God.

Comment: Love does not imply serving his desires. I can love my children but still whoop their behinds when they do the wrong thing.  Indeed, I am compelled to discipline them because I love them.  Love implies doing what is best for them, regardless of what they want.

Comment: @AffableGeek, I agree, and this list isn't meant to be exhaustive, I'm just going through any possibilities of how we can "love" a non-human.  It made sense to take the "Love your neighbor as yourself" and extrapolate it to Satan to see if it made any sense.

Comment: @AffableGeek, Love doesn't imply serving his desires, but they aren't opposites either.  If you love a supernatural being, good or evil, real or imagined, you will serve them.  I don't think the parent-child analogy really applies here, because I'm not trying to make said supernatural being a better person or instruct them.

Answer (score 1):

I know that Satan is PURE EVIL. There is a balance between evil and good. To have pure good in your hearts, you cannot hate, and if we do have hate in our hearts toward Satan, we wouldn't have a 100 percent pure heart. I think it is more of a shame on you, shakes your head, no hope, no trust, disappointment in towards Satan. Why should I hate Satan? Why should I love Satan? I am dissapointed in Satan is all. That is how pure my heart is. God gave us wisdom to know better and use better judgment. Yes, Satan is a fool but, there is nothing anyone can do about it, not even God Himself because again, Satan is PURE EVIL.

Comment: Isn't the expression "pure evil" a contradiction in terms?  Well, maybe not.  If purity denotes that something is unalloyed with even a hint of impurity and is therefore 100 percent of whatever it's supposed to be (e.g., "pure gold" is 24-karat and is unalloyed with anything else), then perhaps Satan is pure evil.  Yeah, I could live with that.

Answer (score 1):

No, we should not love Satan.  Satan (as many contributors, above, have already noted) is not like our human enemies who still have a chance to repent and thus avoid the condemnation of holy, just, and righteous God.  Satan is *already* judged, he's been given a sentence, and he's simply biding his time until he is thrown into his jail cell for all eternity:  hell.  To him, no chance for repentance is given and no one can commute his sentence, since God the righteous judge, who in this case is also the jury, is incapable of error, and His rulings are final.

As Abraham of old so eloquently said,

> "Will not the judge of all the earth do right?"

The answer to Abe's rhetorical question, of course, is yes.  We, being finite, may not understand fully the judgments of God, but we are nevertheless called upon to trust them, since God is trustworthy.

Psalm 19:9 (KJV) tells us,

> "The fear of the LORD is clean, enduring for ever: the judgments of the LORD are true and righteous altogether."

We thank God that His judgment of human beings at both the Great White Throne Judgment and at the Judgment Seat of Christ--the *bema* (see Revelation 20:11-15 and 2 Corinthians 5:10) has yet to take place, which means that within our brief life-span we--unlike Satan--are given a chance to repent and believe.

Though we are, according to Jesus, judged or condemned already because of our unbelief, thanks be to God that whoever believes in Jesus is not subject to the judgment of the lost and condemned.  We praise God, then, for Jesus' having already been judged, sentenced, and condemned to death for us through His cross (see John 3:14-21, particularly vv.16-18).  As Paul said so triumphantly in Romans:

> "But God demonstrates His own love toward us, in that while we were yet sinners, Christ died for us" (5:8).

The righteous One died for the unrighteous ones, the just for the unjust, that He might bring us to God if we simply believe (see 1 Peter 3:18; 1 Corinthians 5:21).

Again, praise the Lord!